# Dell Precision 15 7000 vs Dell Precision M6800

Tags: laptop

Ok, so I want to by a new computer, a mobile workstation. I want some advice on what to choose between these two:

**Dell Precision M6800**

- Intel® Core™ i7-4710MQ (Quad Core 2.50GHz, 3.50GHz Turbo, 6MB 47W, w/HD Graphics 4600)
- Nvidia® Quadro® K3100M w/4GB GDDR5
- 17.3" UltraSharp™ FHD(1920x1080) Wide View Anti-Glare LED-backlit with Premium Panel Guarantee
- 16GB (4x4GB) 1600MHz DDR3L
- 256GB 2.5inch Serial ATA Solid State Drive
- **$2339**

**Dell Precision 7510**

- Intel Xeon E3-1535M v5 (Quad Core 2.90GHz, 3.80GHz Turbo, 8MB 45W, w/Intel HD Graphics P530)
- Nvidia Quadro M2000M w/4GB GDDR5
- 15.6" UltraSharp™ FHD IPS (1920x1080) Wide View Anti-Glare LED-backlit
- 16GB, DDR4-2133MHz SDRAM, 2 DIMMS, ECC
- 256GB 2.5 inch SATA Solid State Drive
- **$2311**

I am buying this laptop for both programming (heavy builds) and intensive graphics operations (video editing in After Effects/Premiere, photography and 3D Graphics). So, what do you think? I tend to choose the second one, but I am not sure about the graphics card...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a Xeon processor allows the use of ECC memory which is sometimes critical for some workloads. You would loose performance for some general purpose but gain a lot more for specialized purposes such as virtualization compared to an i7.

For programming, I would recommend the i7. But because you are doing Premiere and 3D, I would go for the Xeon.

Comment: What about the graphics card?

Comment: @Victor The M2000M is a slightly faster/cooler running card than the K3100M. The M2000M is also one generation newer then the K3100M. So I would go for the M2000M.

Comment: So everything points to the Dell Precision 7510! Thank you very much! I will post a photo with it soon :p